# PhpStorm - WSL2 - Unable to save settings

Tags: phpstorm, settings, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I am using WSL2 with PhpStorm. When I am on a project under WSL2, then when I save a file, I always have the following error:

> Unable to save settings

[image]

I have already tried restarting PhpStorm, and also invalidating the cache, but nothing changes.

Comment: Must be a permissions issue; please share your idea.log. Similar ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-264006; feel free to add your comments there

Comment: Yes it was that, I deleted my .idea folder and recreated it and it works!

Comment: Similar for me. Believe I'd mistakenly opened the project without using \\$wsl path

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that my `.idea` folder was owned by `root`, you can check this by running `ls -la` in your project directory from WSL

```
mford@laptop:~/repo/myproject (master)$ ls -la
total 33
drwxr-xr-x  21 mford mford   4096 Nov 22 15:43 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 mford mford   4096 Nov 17 10:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root    4096 Oct 27 14:44 .idea
-rw-r--r--   1 mford mford   1652 Oct 27 12:26 README.md
```

I resolved this by taking ownership of the folder using `sudo chown -R mford:mford .idea` and PHPStorm now works correctly.